# Execute PowerShell from Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, powershell, rake

This runs fine from the PS command prompt:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -computer "Server" -filter "Name = 'ShareName'"
```

When added to Ruby I can get this to execute (because it doesn't need quotes):

```
powershell (Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -computer "Server")
```

but not with the filter argument (needs quotes):

```
powershell (Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -computer "Server" **-filter "Name = 'ShareName'"**)
```

The output of the error does not show the double quotes. I tried everything I know to escape them and nothing works.

tried `(... -filter \"Name = 'ShareName'\")`
tried `%x{}` instead of ``` `` ```
tried single quotes

Comment: I don't think I see any valid ruby code here.  Could you post your actual ruby code and tell us what you expect it to do versus what it actually does?

Comment: It's executing from a Ruby (well, rake) script. I included Ruby in the tag since it or PowerShell seem to be messing with the quotes or most likely I haven't found the correct sequence of quotes that makes it work. So, the Ruby is `` and %x[] that contains the PS command.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, the value between a double quote string is interpreted, such as an object `$HelloWorld` containing the string "Hello world". Powershell handles `$HelloWorld` the same way it handles `"$helloWorld"`. However if you type `'$HelloWorld'` it will interpret it literally and print the object name, $HelloWorld as a string.

```
PS> $HelloWorld = "Hello World"
PS> $helloworld
Hello World
PS> "$helloworld"
Hello World
PS> '$helloworld'
$helloworld
```

try something like this...

```
PS> "'$helloworld'"
'Hello World'
```